# How do I change a cell in the element-ui table?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, web, vuejs2, vue-component

Hello everyone I wanted to hang the condition on the cells. Let's say we output names in the Name column. If the name is John, then highlight the name in red. When I work in this case, then the whole row is highlighted, but I only want the name in a specific cell.

```js
<script>
  export default {
    methods: {
      tableRowClassName({row, rowIndex}) {
        if (row.name === "John") {
          return 'warning-row';
        } else if (row.name === "Tom") {
          return 'success-row';
        }
        return '';
      }
    },
    data() {
      return {
        tableData:  [{
          date: '2016-05-03',
          name: 'Tom',
          address: 'No. 189, Grove St, Los Angeles'
        }, {
          date: '2016-05-02',
          name: 'John',
          address: 'No. 189, Grove St, Los Angeles'
        }, {
          date: '2016-05-04',
          name: 'Tom',
          address: 'No. 189, Grove St, Los Angeles'
        }, {
          date: '2016-05-01',
          name: 'Tom',
          address: 'No. 189, Grove St, Los Angeles'
        }]
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

```css
<style>
  .el-table .warning-row {
    background: oldlace;
  }

  .el-table .success-row {
    background: #f0f9eb;
  }
</style>
```

```html
<template>
  <el-table
    :data="tableData"
    style="width: 100%"
    :row-class-name="tableRowClassName">
    <el-table-column
      prop="date"
      label="Date"
      width="180">
    </el-table-column>
    <el-table-column
      prop="name"
      label="Name"
      width="180">
    </el-table-column>
    <el-table-column
      prop="address"
      label="Address">
    </el-table-column>
  </el-table>
</template>
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this method.

```
<el-table 
   :data="tableData" 
  :cell-style="cellStyle"
>
</el-table>
```

js

```js
const cellStyle = ({ row, column, rowIndex, columnIndex }) => {
  if (rowIndex === 1 && columnIndex === 1) {
    return {
      backgroundColor: 'pink'
    }
  }
}
```

[image]